# Jordan regular Representative of $H_1(\Omega)$ with coefficients $\mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider the first homology group $H_1(\Omega)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ for a bounded, open subset $\Omega\subset \mathbb C$.  Then I should be able to find a representative path, i.e. it is a regular Jordan curve. Can someone help me with the details, or give me a reference for this?

Comment: I posted an answer, I would be happy if anybody could look over the argument I gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution to this.  First I can find a polygonal representative by simplicial homology theory.  These can intersect (obviously) finite times.  Then one can consider the paths between those intersections.  Since we have coefficients in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ we can freely change the orientation of these curves and glue them in any way together. So the question that needs to be cleared now, if we can do this in a way such that the $n$ components reunite to one simple closed curve. But the answer should be easy. Unless there is only one component; the curves can be combined locally around the intersection points as $\Omega$ is open, such that the number of components is reduced (one should draw a little picture for that, there is always an even number of edges ending at such a multiple intersection point). Using this argument iteratively, we obtain a simple closed curve.